# Is $A\otimes B$ a (left) $R$-module when $A$ and $B$ are right and left $R$-modules respectively?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

$A\otimes B$ is defined to satisfy the property $(ar)\otimes b=a\otimes (rb)$ for all $r\in R$ and $(a,b)\in A\times B$.

Since every element in $A\otimes B$ is generated by elements like $a\otimes b$, it seems to me that I can define $r(a\otimes b)=(ar)\otimes b=a\otimes (rb)$ so that $A\otimes B$ becomes a left $R$-module.

Am i wrong?

Comment: Check associativity, etc.

Comment: @KentaS $(rs)(a\otimes b)=a\otimes (rsb)=r(a\otimes sb)=r(s(a\otimes b))$

Comment: Is R commutative? Else this is false.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff $R$ isn't commutative but why is this false?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I have found the reason that it is false. The definition that $r(a\otimes b)=a\otimes (rb)$ wasn't well definded since $a\otimes b=c\otimes d$ doesn't imply $a\otimes (rb)=c\otimes (rd)$

Comment: I thought you were taking the tensor over $R$?

Comment: The usual thing you can say along these lines is: if $A$ is an $R$-bimodule and $B$ is a left $R$-module, then $A \otimes_R B$ is a left $R$-module with $r(a\otimes b) := (ra) \otimes b$.  And similarly, if $A$ is a right $R$-module and $B$ is an $R$-bimodule, then $A \otimes_R B$ is a right $R$-module.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I am talking the tensor over $R$?